# Using quotient spaces to compute the compactly supported cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^2-D^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $U = \mathbb{R}^2-D^2$ be the open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ equal to the plane minus a closed disk.

The goal is to compute the compute $H_c^n(U)$ by computing $\lim_i H^n(U/(U-K_i))$.

Here is my attempt:

I constructed the compact exhaustion of $U$ to be 2-dimensional rings around $U$ that grow in size to cover $U$. The 2-rings get larger and larger and also closer and closer to the closed disk. Then each 2-ring is quotiented by the inner and outer rings, which gives a 2-sphere. Then $(U/(U-K_i))$ is a 2-sphere for every $i$. So $H_c^n(U)$ is equivalent to the cohomology of a 2-sphere.

**Question**

Does this compact exhaustion work, or is it a problem to have infinitely many disks in an infinitely small space? What other error is there in my reasoning?

Comment: Yes, this was a piece of my previous question. Hopefully three separate questions will be better than putting them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little late, but I hopefully can still help.  The family of annuli that you are using is precisely the correct approach, however when you quotient such a space, you do not get a 2-sphere.  Imagine you have an annulus.  glue the inner edge to the outer edge, you obtain a torus.  Shrink this line you glued along to a point, you obtain what looks like a pinched 2-sphere.  This is the topological space you obtain under the quotient NOT a 2-sphere.  This space's homology can be readily computed using either cellular or preferably singular homology.  For reference, its homology should be $\mathbb{Z}$ in degrees $0,1,2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! You definitely helped me, and your answer made my day. (It's awesome to get an answer that understood my question perfectly, didn't point out my lack of understanding, and also taught me some basic vocabulary -like annulus!- in addition to explaining the answer perfectly. )

Comment: @JuneinJuneau You are too kind.